# Генерация возможных вариантов

Tags: комбинаторика

Как можно сгенерировать все возможные варианты из списка?
К примеру есть список:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Нужно чтобы программа составила все возможные варианты строк:

```
aaa bbb ccc
aaa ccc bbb
bbb aaa ccc
bbb ccc aaa
ccc aaa bbb
ccc bbb aaa
```

Как это вообще сделать?

Бьюсь над решением уже пару дней, но решения найти не могу .

Comment: Находите соответствующий вашей задаче термин из комбинаторики (например, сочетания) и ищете под него алгоритм.

Answer (score 1):

Рекурсивный алгоритм. Реализация на *Python* без использования дополнительных библиотек.

```
def f(lst):
    if len(lst) <= 0:
        return []
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return [lst]

    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(lst)):
        lst2 = list(lst)
        elem = lst2.pop(i)
        sub_result = f(lst2)
        for sr in sub_result:
            l = [elem] + sr
            result.append(l)
    return result

for l in f(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']):
    print(l)
```

Результат выполнения:

```
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
['aaa', 'ccc', 'bbb']
['bbb', 'aaa', 'ccc']
['bbb', 'ccc', 'aaa']
['ccc', 'aaa', 'bbb']
['ccc', 'bbb', 'aaa']
```

---

*Python*, с использованием модуля *itertools*:

```
import itertools

for r in itertools.permutations(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']):
    print(r)
```

Результат выполнения:

```
('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc')
('aaa', 'ccc', 'bbb')
('bbb', 'aaa', 'ccc')
('bbb', 'ccc', 'aaa')
('ccc', 'aaa', 'bbb')
('ccc', 'bbb', 'aaa')
```